# How should I handle a scalability problem during routing my requests from server?

Tags: api, security, server, scalability

I have faced a problem with the initial design of my system where sensitive information was being sent to the front-end and front-end was responsible for calling 3rd party APIs. As you have probably guessed it was extremely vulnerable to attacks. To remedy this I added a back-end system to proxy those requests and call the 3rd party APIs on behalf of front-end. The issue with this approach is it is not scalable at all. I am currently looking at additional 15 servers to handle the current load and it is increasing day by day.

Any advice on how can I remove this back-end requirement? is there any way to make the front-end still call the APIs but secure the data?

Answer (score 0):

So, you simply want to eat the cake and have a cake. Sorry to say that, but there simply is no solution to this problem. Once secrets are passed to the client, he can do anything he wants including calling APIs as no one has intended. To understand it a bit better play with a forward proxy like Burp or OWASP ZAP. You will see how easy it is to modify every request after it has left the browser and every response, before it has reached the browser.

There is usually a some of room for improvements in the optimization on the back-end systems that act as proxies, so I would probably concentrate on that.

Comment: I completely agree with you but the thing is all these extra servers are kind of not ideal to add either.